# AWS Lambda using .NET Core and Google Sheets API

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, google-sheets-api

I'm writing an Alexa skill that uses an AWS Lambda function using the C# runtime (.NET Core), and am trying to connect to a Google Sheet using their API. It throws a missing DLL exception during runtime:

> The type initializer for 'System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyLite' threw an exception.
>
> at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyLite.ImportKeyBlob(String blobType, Byte[] keyBlob)
>
> at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.ImportKeyBlob(Byte[] rsaBlob, Boolean includePrivate)
>
> at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.ImportParameters(RSAParameters parameters)
>
> at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer.FromPrivateKey(String privateKey)
>
> at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateServiceAccountCredentialFromParameters(JsonCredentialParameters credentialParameters)
>
> at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialFromParameters(JsonCredentialParameters credentialParameters)
>
> at AlexaProjLib.GoogleSheet.Connect()
>
> at AlexaProj.Function.FunctionHandler(SkillRequest input, ILambdaContext context)

Inner exception:

> Unable to load DLL 'ncrypt.dll': The specified module could not be found.

Code:

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(_googleSecret).CreateScoped(_scopes);

Service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = _applicationName,
});
```

I'm pretty new to .NET Core and Lambda - how do I get the missing DLL correctly referenced?

Comment: Sanity check: Are you including your dependencies in the zip that you push up to lambda? Lambda can't restore packages.

Comment: @AnthonyNeace I downloaded the zip from AWS and poked around - it certainly doesn't contain a ncrypt.dll, nor a System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyLite. There doesn't appear to be a CngKeyLite package in NuGet, but there is a System.Security.Cryptography.Cng (which doesn't seem to resolve the issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that I was defining a Windows runtime in the project.json file (win10-x64), which was causing these runtime errors (AWS Lambda runs on Amazon Linux). Ended up getting it compiled and running by using **dotnet lambda package**, with more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868476/aws-lambda-and-net-core-using-a-linux-runtime/42874741#42874741).

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the instructions provided in [this github forum](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3783) as other users encountered it also.

```
execute
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/

instead of
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2h_1/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2h_1/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib

if you receive "File exists" message ln -sf will do the magic..

ln -sf /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -sf /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```